# Set value to a global scope from a local scope in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to pass the argument from addSpouse() to the form element family ID.
Please note that Family ID/the form is on another page accessed through the ng-click action of the addSpouse function.

**Code**

```
ourladyApp.controller('formController',
    function($scope, $http, $location) {
        $scope.formData = {};

        $scope.formData.familyid = '';

        $scope.processForm = function() {
            var url = "/ourlady/newlead";
            var config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                }
            };
            $http.post(url, $.param($scope.formData), config)
                .success(function(data) {
                    $location.path('/logged');
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.handleErrorInDialogs(status);
                });
        };

        $scope.addSpouse = function(pi) {
            $scope.formData.familyid = pi;
            $location.path('/profile');
        }

    }
);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/babaphemy/4uhs6o6t/)

Kindly assist .
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by global scope & local scope in your question..how can I decide which is global and which is local..at least could you make your fiddle working

Comment: what about passing it in the URL and getting it as a $routeParam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the code snippet to set the state

```
$scope.setState = function(view){

    localStorage.setItem("view", (view)


 }
```

and then get current state in my submit form action called by the ng-submit (shown beow) :

```
$scope.processForm = function() {
```

var currentState =   localStorage.getItem("view");

}

Answer (score 0):

You may use $rootScope. It will give you more options for binding/watching than localStorage.